# Django: Module not Found on Azure App Service - Azure DevOps CD

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am looking to set up a simple Django application on Azure App Service (Linux OS) by running an Azure Devops Build and Release pipeline.  The application builds and creates a release without a problem.

However when the application has been released it runs into runtime errors.

```
2019-10-15T09:48:16.161816610Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

I run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` as part of the bash post deployment script, and requirements.txt contains Django but it claims the requirement is already satisfied.  Or if I bash into the App Service and run the same command it get the same message with the requirements already being satisfied.

Therefore my question is, why am I receiving a ModuleNotFoundError?

Comment: Activate your virtualenv first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very normal issue we would meet during the application runtime. About the issue you are facing, there has different situations need to be considered.

**1. If you has `virtualenv`, ensure the state of `virtualenv` is activated.**

With the follow command to activate the `virtualenv`:

```
$ source ./{env-name}/bin/activate
```

For details info, you can check this [doc](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/26/python-virtual-env/).

**2. Ensure the path of module is correct in `Wsgi` file:**

For python runtime, it has [Python module search path](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). If you did not specified the module path in `Wsgi` file, it will not get and read the `Django` module.

In your `Wsgi` file, it should has these script:

```
 sys.path.append(<module-path})
```

If you has specified the path, but still has the issue, please check this [blog](https://alex.dzyoba.com/blog/python-import/) which described the **sibling** package.

Here has one detailed [blog](https://tmont.es/2018/virtual-environment-fundamentals/index.html) which about the `virtualenv` and package path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Merlin Liang - MSFT.  I tried your suggestion of activating a virtualenv but noy joy.  `Module Not Found virtualenv` in the release pipeline.  Here is my post deployment script.  
    `pip3 install virtualenv --user`
    `python3 -m virtualenv env`
    `source env/bin/activate`
    `pip3 install -r requirements.txt --user`

Comment: I tried the 2nd option and added in the location of site-packages where the pip modules where getting installed and that worked.  I never had much luck with the virtualenv.  Seems to you don't get the permissions to run source on kudu.